# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3 50"

Tags: java, exception, program-entry-point

I am using the Netbeans IDE for my code. I am getting this error when I try to run it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3    50"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at spacely.sprockets.broc.east.SpacelySprocketsBrocEast.main(SpacelySprocketsBrocEast.java:32)
```

I have not been able to pick out the errors that would cause this in the program. My code is below. If anyone can point me in the right direction I will be incredibly grateful. Thanks.

```
 package spacely.sprockets.broc.east;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
 import java.io.IOException;

 public class SpacelySprocketsBrocEast
 {


     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         BufferedReader br = null;
         BufferedWriter bw = null;

        try
        {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sprocketorders.txt"));
            String line;
            String element[] = new String[2];
            int   sum[] = new int[5];
            File file = new File ("sprocketorders.txt");

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                element = line.split(" ");

                switch(Integer.parseInt(element[0]))
                {
                    case 1:
                        sum[0] = sum[0] + Integer.parseInt(element[1]);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        sum[1] = sum[1] + Integer.parseInt(element[1]);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        sum[2] = sum[2] + Integer.parseInt(element[1]);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        sum[3] = sum[3] + Integer.parseInt(element[1]);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        sum[4] = sum[4] + Integer.parseInt(element[1]);
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (!file.exists())
            {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write("Spacely Sprockets\nTaking Sprockets into the Future\nSales Summary Report\nSprocket Number Total Quantity Sold\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < sum.length; i++)
                bw.write((i + 1) + "\t" + sum[i] + "\n");

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
                if (bw != null)
                    bw.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

     }

 }
```

Comment: Step through your code using a debugger, and see what `element[1]` is when your code is trying to parse it as an Integer

Comment: I tried to use a debugger within netbeans and it returned the same exception error I posted above in the output window. Then in the debugger console all it said is this: Listening on javadebug User program running Debugger stopped on uncompilable source code. User program finished

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems to be fairly explicit. Java does not know how to interpret `3    50` as a single integer.

If you want to know why, use a debugger or put print statements before that line. The last few prints before the exception is thrown should be illuminating.

Comment: I tried to use a debugger within netbeans and it returned the same exception error I posted above in the output window. Then in the debugger console all it said is this:
Listening on javadebug
User program running
Debugger stopped on uncompilable source code.
User program finished

Comment: If your debugger is buggy, I'd recommend inserting `print` statements instead of debugging your debugger. A working debugger would enable you to check the value of different variables at the time the crash happened.

Comment: Well I'm new to the Java programming world and not 100% sure what print statements you are saying to add and where to add them. Maybe I am over thinking it but I've been scratching my head with this program for a while.